# Why do I get NAN for p-values while using statsmodels logit function?

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, statsmodels

[My data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PUPWoS_7XsmplDG_mFjjOis-IopPnRVM/view?usp=sharing)

I used statsmodels to build a logistic regression as follows:

```
X = np.copy(train_data)
X = sm_.add_constant(X)

model = sm.Logit(train_y, X)

result = model.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=10000)

p_values[i-1, j-1, :] = result.pvalues
logistic_Coefficients[i-1, j-1, :] = result.params
```

But I get the following error and my p-values are all NAN:

```
C:\Users\maryamr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:488: HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
  'available', HessianInversionWarning)
C:\Users\maryamr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Users\maryamr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:879: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)
C:\Users\maryamr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1821: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)
```

I also tried glm in r and I get the following error but just one of the features has NAN coefficient and p-value.

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Comment: You could also try statsmodels GLM with Binomial family which has better boundary handling than Logit. That might work around the numerical problem, but will not be a solution to the theoretical problem with perfect prediction or separation

Comment: Hessian inversion can fail if you have a column that is constant as well, so look out for that. Look out for very low frequency binary variables if you're not using stratified sampling!

Answer (score 4):

R/GLM and statsmodels.GLM have different ways of handling "perfect separation" (which is what is happening when fitted probabilities are 0 or 1).  In Statsmodels, a fitted probability of 0 or 1 creates Inf values on the logit scale, which propagates through all the other calculations, generally giving NaN values for everything.

There are many ways of dealing with perfect separation.  One option is to manually drop variables until the situation resolves. There are also some automated approaches.  Statsmodels has elastic net penalized logistic regression (using `fit_regularized` instead of `fit`).  But this will give you point estimates without standard errors.  The statsmodels master has conditional logistic regression.  I don't think Statsmodels has Firth's method.

Edited: reading your question again, it looks like the optimization converged but the Hessian was not invertible.  This is a related but less severe version of what I described above.  But the same advice still applies.